# Foreach loop returning database search results to a view in cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `CourseSearchResultMode` to `IEnumerable`. An explicit conversion exists (are
>   you missing a cast?)

Controller:

```
namespace RedPandaCourses.Controllers
{
    public class SearchController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CourseSearchView()
        {
            var courses = new CourseSearchResultModel();
            return View(courses);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult CourseSearchView(CourseSearchResultModel vm)
        {
            var courses = new CourseSearchResultModel();
            return View(courses);
        }
```

2 Models:

```
namespace RedPandaCourses.Models
{
    public class CourseSearchModel
    {
        public CourseSearchModel() { }
        public string courseName { get; set; }
        public int courseNumber { get; set; }
        public string courseInstructor { get; set; }
        public List<CourseSearchResultModel> results { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace RedPandaCourses.Models
{
    public class CourseSearchResultModel
    {
        public CourseSearchResultModel() { }
        public decimal courseID { get; set; }
        public string courseName { get; set; }
        public string courseNumber { get; set; }
        public string courseInstructorFirstName { get; set; }
        public string courseInstructorLastName { get; set; }
        public string courseInstructor { get; set; }
        public string courseSchedule { get; set; }

    }
}
```

It will send text box text to the database, search it from a select class, and return the results to the table using a foreach loop, however the foreach loop throws the error above.
View:

```
@Model RedPandaCourses.Models.CourseSearchResultModel;
@using RedPandaCourses.Models;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CourseSearchView";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}

<div class="container-fluid no-main-border">
    <div class="row-fluid main-bg">
        <div class="span12">
            <h2 class="labelHide">&nbsp;</h2>

            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="negMargin">
                    <div class="span9 inner-container">
                        <div class="streamlined-subhead">
                            <h1>Search Courses</h1>
                        </div>
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("CourseSearchView", "Search"))
                        {
                            var model = new CourseSearchModel();
                            <div id="the_id" class="question">
                                <div class="control-group" id="the_id_control-group">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div id="the_id_1_control-group" class="control-group">
                                            <label class="control-label" for="courseName">Course Name: </label>
                                            <div id="the_id_1_controls" class="controls">
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => model.courseName)
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="the_id_2_control-group" class="control-group">
                                            <label class="control-label" for="courseNumber">Course Number: </label>
                                            <div id="the_id_2_controls" class="controls">
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => model.courseNumber)
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="the_id_3_control-group" class="control-group">
                                            <label class="control-label" for="instructor">Instructor: </label>
                                            <div id="the_id_3_controls" class="controls">
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => model.courseInstructor)
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="previous-next-bar">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="courseSearch" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("CourseSearchView","Search")'">Search</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                        <div>
                            <h2>Search Results</h2>
                            <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover dataTable width80">
                                <thead class="tableHeader" role="rowgroup">
                                    <tr role="row">
                                        <th class="sorting" role="columnheader"><a href="#">Course Title</a></th>
                                        <th class="sorting" role="columnheader"><a href="#">Course Number</a></th>
                                        <th class="sorting" role="columnheader"><a href="#">Instructor</a></th>
                                        <th class="sorting" role="columnheader"><a href="#">Schedule</a></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @if (Model == null)
                                    {
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="4">no results</td>
                                        </tr>                                       
                                    } else { 
                                    foreach (var item in Model)
                                    {
                                        Html.AntiForgeryToken();
                                        <tr class="clickableRow" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("InstructorCourseDetailView", "Instructor")'">
                                            <td>@Html.Encode(item.courseName)</td>
                                            <td>@Html.Encode(item.courseNumber)</td>
                                            <td>@Html.Encode(item.courseInstructor)</td>
                                            <td>@Html.Encode(item.courseSchedule)</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    }
                                    }
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="4">
                                            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AdminAddCourseView","Admin")'">Add Course</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="previous-next-bar">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AdminHome","Admin")'">Return</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've looked everywhere including a bunch of questions on this site and cannot find anything that has helped me in this situation. I'm new to coding, this is the training application I'm doing for my new job and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to answer that question? I'm very new to this type of coding.

Comment: I assume you want `foreach (var item in Model.results)` - but that will also throw an exception because you have not initialized that property and it will be `null`

Comment: Yes, I had Model.results at one point and it gives the error:
'RedPandaCourses.Models.CourseSearchResultModel' does not contain a definition for 'results'

Comment: When I try using 
public List<CourseSearchResultModel> results { get; set; }
(not sure if that is correct)
I end up with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Your model needs to know that it's getting a List rather than a single instance. Try this in your model @Model List<RedPandaCourses.Models.CourseSearchResultModel>; Then you need to make sure you're sending multiple instances.

Comment: @mjwills, OP wants the view based on `CourseSearchModel` (have a look at the ridiculous `var model = new CourseSearchModel();` in the view :)

Comment: I tried that in my view"@Model List<RedPandaCourses.Models.CourseSearchResultModel>.. and I get the same error.. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: I did add a results property into the coursesearchmodel model but it doesn't seem to change anything
  public List<CourseSearchResultModel> results { get; set; }

Comment: Your creating/editing a `CourseSearchModel` so therefore you need to return a `CourseSearchModel` and your view will be `@model CourseSearchModel`. But your loop (which needs to be `foreach (var item in Model.results)` will throw an exception because the `results` property is `null` (you never initialize it)

Comment: On what on earth are you trying to do with the `onclick="..."` in your submit button - that makes no sense at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, the form should sending a CourseSearchModel not a CourseSearchResultModel.

Second, in the action handling the post, you should query the database and put the result in the results property of the search model you received as an argument. Here is how to do it :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
//Change the type of the object bound from the from 
public ActionResult CourseSearchView(CourseSearchModel vm)
{
    //Query the db and put the outcome in the results prop of the vm
    vm.results = QueryTheDb();
    //return the vm to the view
    return View(vm);
}
```

Third, you give that object to the View method in the return line.

Fourth, change this

```
@Model RedPandaCourses.Models.CourseSearchResultModel;
```

with this

```
@Model RedPandaCourses.Models.CourseSearchModel;
```

in your view.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the second part. I do have a select class setup in my data access layer for doing the searching to the database I made..
public Models.CourseSearchModel CourseSearchModel(Models.CourseSearchModel vm)

Comment: Where would I get my "QueryTheDb();" from. I have that in a folder called "DAL" and then the class is called "Select".. that particular search is with "public Models.CourseSearchModel CourseSearch(Models.CourseSearchModel vm)" and return the vm.. I was thinking it would then be "DAL.Select();" but that doesn't work so I must be offbase.

Comment: You should replace QueryTheDb(); with whatever query logic you have.